# Where can I make mock http calls to learn Angular2 frontend http calls

Tags: http, angular2-services

I am trying to learn Angular2 and I want to learn how to make all http calls and GET, POST, PUT, DELETE data from my Angular2 frontend.

I went through the Angular2 website and made the heroes app through the tutorial they have. But they used in-memory mock data.

For real-world applications, I will make http calls (first test API's using postman like application) and then perform http operations.

Do I need to make any backend part to perform this or is there any other way possible like a test website where I can get URL's and make http calls to learn all calls above and improve my knowledge.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are few HTTP mocking services & tools:

- http://www.mocky.io
- http://wiremock.org

More at https://www.google.ie/search?q=mock+http